# applying fine-grained control over scale out

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, azure-functions

I have a blob-triggered function that will take the contents of the blob and send it to an sftp drop location.

Depending on the sftp destination, I need to be able to control the scale out.

For example:
If destination == 'sftp.alex.com' then scale the function out to no more than 5 instances, if destination == 'sftp.othersite.com' then scaleOut to no more than 20.

Blob example:

```
{
  "payload":"binary-formatted string",
  "destination":"sftp.alex.com"
}
```

**Is this type of fine-trained control over the scale out of the azure function available?**

Answer (score 1):

> Is this type of fine-trained control over the scale out of the azure function available?

No, it's impossible.

For Consumption Plan, you can't directly affect the scaling algorithm of Azure Functions. This serverless plan scales [automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan), and you're charged for compute resources only when your functions are running.

For App Service Plan, you can scale out instance count [manually or automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json).

Blob Trigger specifically has some known limitations. Particularly, there are might be **delays in processing blob**. For faster scaling, I suggest you using `Event Grid triggers`, which should scale pretty well for both "priority" and "non-priority" customers of yours. Refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149002/scale-azure-function-through-c-sharp-code).

Comment: indeed ill use the event grid trigger for this per your suggestion, i would like to learn about how to scale automatically with the app service plan. any guidance on how to implement what i need?

Comment: This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service%2ftoc.json) is about how to configure auto scale and this [one](https://camerondwyer.com/2019/03/07/azure-app-service-my-experience-with-auto-scale-out/) is about testing.