# ensuring no more than N instances are scaled out for a specific queue

Tags: c#, queue, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-queues

My function is sending a payload to different sftp servers. Those servers are limited in how many connections they can accept.

I need a solution to throttle our connections to those servers.

The function is triggered by storage queues, and the first draft of the design is:

[image]

I then learned that you can only have 1 trigger per function, which led me to sandwhich another aggregating queue:

[image]

I can set the [batchSize/newBatchThreshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json) on the originating queues, but I'm not certain this will work because the originating queues will not be aware of when to push messages to the *aggregate queue*.

1. I need the function to not scale out to more than N instances for all messages from queue X, since the sftp server X will not accept more than N connections.
2. Additionally, I need the function to scale out to no more than M instances for all messages from queue Y, since the sftp server Y will not accept more than M connections.

**The total instances would be M + N for the above scenario.**

How do we adjust our design in order to fit these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 100% bullet-proof solution to this, the issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/511).

The best way could be setting `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to `1` in application settings of the Function App which is triggered by the aggregate queue. Then, you should only get one concurrent instance of the Function App, so the `batchSize` setting will actually be useful for rate limiting.

You don't need to limit queue processors X/Y/Z in this case, let the messages flow to the aggregate.

Now, I didn't understand if only messages from queue X touch SFPT X, or it's many-to-many. If it's one-on-one, it makes sense to get rid of the aggregate queue, have three Functions and limit the concurrency for each of the queues separately.

Anyway, the limit settings are as I suggested above.

In case this still doesn't satisfy your requirements, you may switch to another messaging service. For instance, send all messages of one type into a separate session of Service Bus or a single partition of Event Hub, which will naturally limit the concurrency on the broker level.

Comment: thanks so much! unfortunately i cannot take your suggestion `have three Functions and limit the concurrency for each of the queues separately.` because i might have 100 queues for 100 different destinations

Comment: well, maybe it would be hard to manage, but it could work for 100 too :) If you combine all 100 into one aggregate, I don't think you would be able to limit all of those to match the exact limit of each destination. Instead, you'd have to set very conservating values and leave the outliers to retries.

Comment: so your suggestion is create 100 queues, with 100 function apps, setting the WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT to 1 for every single functoin app, right/?

Comment: im thinking perhaps this is a durable function problem? any other guidance on this? im very stuck on what to do, ive read dozens of your posts and hundreds of others and really cannot think of an architectural suitable solution, i'm open to any suggestions, perhaps an event hub would be helpful in this case? but not sure

Comment: 100 queues are possible but sound complicated. durable could be one approach, although I'd have to think of the exact approach. how many messages/sec do those queues handle? how about service bus or event hubs I suggested?

Comment: how would service bus or event hubs aid in ensuring that only X number of instances are spinned up for a specific destination?

Comment: You can shift smartness on the sender side and spread messages among sessions. Functions would then not handle multiple messages of the same session in parallel. So, the max parallelism is limited by the number of sessions.

Comment: so you are saying that the sender will batch exacty the amount of messages that should be processed at once and the receiver will pick this batch up in a `session` which means 1 instance per session, correct?

Comment: No, the sender just needs to send all X messages to session X1, X2, X3, then you won't have more than 3 handlers for X. We are getting close to the limit of comments, maybe add a separate detailed question for those

Comment: spasibo! im looking into event hubs, where i will first have a function that combines blobs into _batches_ then that function will have an output binding to event hubs, then that event will be like `EventData[]` trigger for another function that will be durable, and it iterate and fan out the actually uploading activity

Comment: im still ignorant regarding  your service bus solution; however, it seems like it would be similar to event hubs

Comment: To correct a little bit: You won't need 100 function apps. You need 100 functions in 1 function app, with WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT set to 1. Probably a bit easier to manage than 100 apps.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Depend on the sftp's error response**

Does the sftp server return a 429 (too many requests) response? Or something similar? When you get such a response, you can just exit from the function without deleting the message from the queue. The message will become *visible* again after 30 seconds, and would trigger a function. 30 seconds is the default value of `visibilitytimeout` and is [customizable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#leverage-additional-options-for-de-queuing-messages) [on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages) a per-msg basis.

**Option 2: Distributed locks**

I don't know from top of my head a distributed locking solution with counters. An alternative would be to implement a locking solution on your own using a SQL db and atomic transactions. A function when processing a message from Queue X will look into the db to see if a lock counter for X is less than N, and increase it by 1 if so, and then process the message. In this case, you will have to make sure that the locks get released even if your function crashes. That is, implement locks with lease expiration time.